# Selecting all columns from a table but casting certain columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I've read through other similar questions but can't find an answer

I have a SQL query such as:

```
SELECT * FROM tblName
```

`tblName` has several columns e.g. id, name, date etc

I would like to cast `id` as `bigint`.

However, in my application, tblName is dynamic. So a user has a list of all the tables in the DB. Let's say 1000 tables. The application then gets all columns from that table. The only column each table has in common is the `id` column.

The application is using Flask and pyodbc so any larger numbers get converted to decimal/float which is a whole other headache. The workaround is to cast the int as bigint within SQL.

Is this possible? I'm unable to rewrite any part of the application so therefore asking if it can be done in SQL

Comment: You need to list the columns you need *explicitly* and `CAST`/`CONVERT` the column `id`. Using `SELECT *` in application code and object definitions is a poor idea to start with.

Comment: "I'm unable to rewrite any part of the application" - that's not a good sign.

Comment: It's a 3rd party application that we can't access. I just happen to know it's using Python and hence why this is an issue.

Comment: If you have `SELECT “` hard-coded in the application, your options are limited. I suppose you could create a new database, generate a view there for each original table that performs the convert on those columns, and point the app’s connection string at the new database. But then you’d have to add views for every new table. Good grief, fix the app (or explain to the 3rd party vendor what a crappy job they’ve done and so they should fix it).

Comment: What Aaron said -- you don't necessarily need a new database, you could create the views in their own schema and change the user's default schema to that, as most applications are not schema-aware and won't prefix their object names with any. This may fail depending on how "the list of all the tables" is retrieved, however -- and of course it will break not only if tables are added, but also for every schema modification of existing tables, so you're probably looking at a periodic job. Not fun at all and definitely worth changing the application over.

Comment: I must admit, however, it seems odd that you need to convert your `id` column to a `bigint`. If the column should be a `bigint`, should you not changing the underlying table? If `id` is defined as an `int` then it can't have any values greater than the value outside of an `int`; or is the column defined as a `decimal(n,0)`?

Comment: It's the python engine more than anything doing this. The int come through fine in SSMS but when it hits Python so maybe this needs to become a Python question more than SQL but I am unable to change the application code

Comment: If the app code is broken and doesn't handle simple data types correctly, I still think you should be reaching out to the vendor for support. They wrote a bad app and should fix it, or at least be able to explain to you why they are converting an int to a decimal (and maybe you could explain why that causes a problem).

Comment: ...and how converting to a bigint (without changing the table) could possibly _solve_ that problem.

Comment: @JeroenMostert I was being conservative and assumed that _maybe_ the schemas are hard-coded (I do preach about that quite a bit).

Comment: It's not the app as such - seems an issue with pyodbc more than anything else, I was just seeing if there was a workaround (a simple one) in SQL